# How to PACT test UI - GraphQL - back-end stack

Tags: graphql, pact

We have micro-services with the following architecture:

web-ui <-> graphQL <-> n * back-end services

We are implementing PACT consumer driven contract tests which is working well between the back-end services.

However there are questions on how to implement this through the graphQL layer. In reality this is a consumer of the back-end services, and a provider to the web-ui.

As the consumer, GraphQL doesn't have the domain information for the actual required json that is initiated from the web-ui service. Then the web-ui service doesn't test against the back-end providers (as the graphQL layer is its provider) - and it hasn't got that association / knowledge of the back-end services.

Is it that graphQL should create a PACT interaction with each back-end provider containing all its potential values with each service. Then this demonstrates that those interfaces remain compliant. Thus the real request (interaction) from the user (web-ui) has pacts with the GraphQL service (with mocks of the back-end services), so implicitly would work all the way through the stack.

Has anyone got advice of how this works across this aggregation layer?